# Issue while loggin into aem after integrating sso

Tags: adobe, aem, aem-6

After integrating sso with aem I am able to login(after giving required credentials keep on switching between urls) into aem instance but unable to see welcome.html page as I can see infinite loop is happening in the browser between idp end point url and welcome page of aem. Added the idp url to apache referrer filter section as well. Still issue exits.Can someone suggest and help how to fix this issue.

Comment: If you record the network requests in your browser, are there any error messages? Usually, with oauth or saml, you can see what information is exchanged -  maybe AEM is missing some information. Or you got your config wrong in AEM. Anyway, the requests + error.log will give you more details.

Comment: Also, you can create a specific logger for authentication classes (org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.security.authentication) in debug level, to get more info.

Comment: Hi oliver and ronnyfm ,thanks for your response on this. It works there is an error in osgi handler for name id format. Fixed that now it works.